PNPM-NX | Failed to create a workspace
Failed NX
I am creating a NX monorepo with PNPM, and getting an issue as shown in the image
How did I create a workspace? I did with this script
pnpx create-nx-workspace nest-workspace1 --preset=nest


How can I solve this? I have Windows OS.
Should not be show that failed to create a workspace message, has to shown successfully created workspace.

I encountered the same issue with pnpm.
My command: npx create-nx-workspace@latest my-project-name --package-manager=pnpm
The error message was identical to yours.
After digging into the logs, I found the solution. My log file was located here: C:\Users\{{user}}\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-7248-SUuL8e0BqDGA\error.log.
In my log analysis, I noticed two instances of NX Generating @nx/workspace:preset and the error NX Cannot create a new project my-project-name at apps/my-project-name. A project already exists in this directory. appearing after the second command. To resolve this, I ran the same command again but deleted the my-project-name and my-project-name-e2e directories from apps as soon as they were created. The script then regenerated those directories, and everything worked as expected! 
I hope this helps you or anyone else facing the same issue.
